# How can I change my pictures' and videos' date on my phone by their filenames?

Tags: photos, file-management, scripts, ftp, exif

Yesterday, I moved a bunch of old pictures and videos to my phone, using a FTP server I installed on my phone. Everything went fine, but today I discovered that the date of all the copied photos and videos was set to yesterday. As a result, my photos and videos are now showing up in the wrong order in the Gallery app.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: screenshot]

Luckily, the date and time is still preserved in the filenames. Right now, I want to restore the photos' and videos' date using their filenames.

I'm interested in a way to do so. I don't really care whether it's by using an app or script or something else.

I'm aware of the fact that I can copy the files from my computer to the phone again using a different protocol, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a <sup><sub>rather dirty</sub></sup> script to do this. For this to work, I'm assuming you have a rooted device, and the directory that contains the pictures and videos is `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`. If otherwise, change the script.

1. Download [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) and install it. This is needed for executing Linux shell commands.
2. Create a script called `script.sh`, containing this block of code, and put it on the root of your sd card.

   ```
   cd DCIM/Camera
   echo "Navigated to `pwd`"

   ls

   for f in *.jpg *.3gp *.m4v
   do

     [ -e $f ] || continue    ## testing if the file exists
     NEWDATE=`echo $f | sed 's|IMG_||g' | sed 's|VID_||g' | sed 's|_||g' | \
     sed 's|.3gp||g'  | sed 's|.m4v||g' | sed 's|.jpg||g' | sed 's|........|&\.|g'`

     echo "Touching date $NEWDATE into $f..."

     touch -t "$NEWDATE" "$f" ## using touch to insert the new date into the file

   done
   ```
3. Start adb shell, and execute:

   ```
   su
   mount -o remount rw /sdcard
   ```

   to make sure you can actually edit the files
4. Move to your sd card:

   ```
   cd /sdcard
   ```
5. Execute the shell script:

   ```
   sh script.sh
   ```
6. Now start the Gallery app, and wait. Especially if you have a large file collection, it may take Android a while to sort everything and update the cache.

Answer (score 1):

If the EXIF data is correct, you can use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/). Note that this only works for JPEG files.

First, check if the files still have correct EXIF data using:

```
jhead <file>
```

Then use jhead's `-ft` option:

> `-ft` Sets the file's system time stamp to what is stored in the Exif header.

```
jhead *.jpg
```

Comment: Sounds good, but is there a binary for Android anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change timestamp of **images** with many image viewers. For example in FastStone Viewer: *Tools -> Change Timestamp* -> choose the creation date from EXIF. You can select all your images before and apply this function on all of them at once.

My only idea about videos is a script, that parses a name and sets the file attribute.

Comment: Do you know any app that can do that directly on android? Ty.

Answer (score 0):

This is an app you can make yourself, or I can do it for you if you so wish. It involves file manipulation using the Java File API or Unix shell tools, whichever you prefer. I think that if you have any programming experience at all the Java API documentation is a good place to start. Or, if you have Windows, you can use an extension to Windows explorer called QTTabbar ([qttabbar.sourceforge.net](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/)) which has an option to copy files while preserving the last modified date. I suggest copying the files from your computer to the phone using a USB cable.